# Sql 2000 data format using a group by query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

There is a table with below mentioned sample data.I need to get a result set in a specific format.

Original table

```
   org  type    value
    a   1   1000
    a   2   200
    b   1   1020
    b   2   100
    c   1   890
    c   2   20
```

Required Result set

```
org     value

a       (1000-2000)/1000
b       (1020-100)/1020
c       (890-20)/890
```

How to achieve this using SQL 2000.Do I ahve to pivot to get the org wise values as shown above?

Comment: Where do you get the "2000"????

Comment: Self join `WHERE Type=1, WHERE Type=2 ON t1.org=t2.org`

Comment: Some of our dbs are still 2000!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No

```
select t1.org, (t1.value - t2.value) / t1.value
From myTable t1
inner join myTable t2 on t1.org = t2.org and t1.type = 1 and t2.type = 2
```

should do it, given there's always a type 1 and type 2 for each org

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp (
    Org VARCHAR(50)
    ,[type] INT
    ,value DECIMAL(18, 2)
    )

INSERT #tmp (Org,[type],value)
VALUES ('a',1,1000)
    ,('a',2,200)
    ,('b',1,1020)
    ,('b',2,100)
    ,('c',1,890)
    ,('c',2,20)

SELECT t1.Org
    ,(t1.Value-t2.value) / t1.Value [Math Done]
    ,'('+convert(varchar(10),t1.Value) +'-' 
       + convert(varchar(10),t2.Value)+')/'
       +convert(varchar(10),t1.Value) [Math Shown]
FROM (SELECT Org, Value FROM #tmp WHERE Type = 1) t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT Org, Value FROM #tmp WHERE Type = 2) t2
    ON t1.Org = t2.Org

DROP TABLE #tmp
```

Results:

```
Org Math Done               Math Shown
a   0.8000000000000000000   (1000.00-200.00)/1000.00
b   0.9019607843137254901   (1020.00-100.00)/1020.00
c   0.9775280898876404494   (890.00-20.00)/890.00
```

Working example, if you want to display the math instead of just doing it.